# Replace relative links with absolute links inside a given text using regex or str_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a text like:

```
61  me  xxxx.com
60  aici    xxx.com/ 
59  here    9gag.com
```

Some links have http:// in front of them, some don't.
I want to replace the urls with

```
'http://'.$url
```

So here's what I've done:

My links are in the following array:

```
$links
```

And I do this:

```
foreach($links as $link){
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $link)) {
        $links2[] = "http://" . $link;
    }
}
```

And afterwards:

```
$str=str_replace($links, $links2, $str);
```

My text now shows:

```
61      me      http://http://http://http://http://http:// 
60      aici    http://http://http://http://http://
59      here    http://http://http://http://http://
```

Sorry for the formatting of the text.

LATER EDIT:

In other words it does not replace correctly the links, it just puts "http://" several times.
Any ideas why it does that? Any better solutions for this?

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you show the content of `$links`?

Comment: have you tried exactly the text 61  me  xxxx.com
60  aici    xxx.com/ 
59  here    9gag.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDITED

---

I think it's the [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function that's causing it because it's actually not respecting what comes before (which is the very job of `preg_*` functions).

I'm suggesting quite a different approach here. Sorry for changing my answer all over.

```
$links = array(
    'xxxx.com',
    'xxx.com/',
    '9gag.com',
    'www.google.com'
);

foreach ($links as &$link) $link = preg_quote($link,'~');
// make each array item quoted/ready for use in a pattern
unset($link);
// delete reference

$rx = '~\b(?<!(?<=ftp|ftps|http|https)://)(' . implode('|',$links) . ')\b~i';
// first word boundary character eliminates links like "axxx.com"
// implode part makes it (xxxx\.com|xxx\.com|9gag\.com|www\.google\.com)
// and first parentesized part basically says
// "not preceded by ftp:// ftps:// http:// https://"
$str = "Here are some links: xxxx.com, axxx.com, http://www.google.com";
var_dump($str);

$str = preg_replace($rx,'http://$0',$str);
// replace all applicable links
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and mine, yours simply does the replacement using reference.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Sorry for not being specific about the reason in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead based regex like this to put `http://` wherever it is necessary like this:

```
// assuming your input file is input.txt
$lines = file("input.txt");
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $arr = explode(' ', $line);
    $arr[2] = preg_replace('#(?!^https?://)^(.+)$#i', 'http://$1', $arr[2]);
    $line = implode(' ', $arr);
    echo $line;
}
```